# How to execute a test as part of bash string as executable command?

Tags: bash

If I have a "file" that includes...

```
rm -rf /etc/motd
if [ -f /etc/motd]; then rm -rf /etc/motd; fi
```

And I try to do...

```
while read -r line 
do 
  command ${line}
  #$(${line})
  #eval ${line}
done< "file"
```

The 1st line runs of course.  But the 2nd command fails with if : command not found.  Which I understand the error because not an explicit command.  So the question is how to execute a test as part of a string as bash script logic?  I tried eval, and $(), i.e. subshells, but still errors out?  Tripping over the 'if' test.  I need a conditional test before the command/script code is executed in a one-liner.  There has to be a way to do this, right?

Comment: Ok, eval actually does work... right? Guess I goofed up when testing 'eval' method.  But is there a better way in total, to do this type of thing?

Comment: `if [ -f /etc/motd]`, add a space after `d`.

Comment: If you're going to use `eval`, you should double-quote the variable (`eval "$line"`) to prevent even weirder than usual parsing. But what about `source file`?

Comment: Be Careful with `eval` (it's commented above and only one-character different than `evil`) What if `$line`evaluated to `rm -rf /` where everything following the `'/'` failed to expand?

Comment: Missing space was just a typo by the way when I typed the question up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to load and execute "`file`" from another script just do

```
source "file"
```

no need to loop over the lines.